# Does the max current rating vary with voltage for this connector?

Tags: voltage, current, connector

Regarding [this](https://docs.rs-online.com/d87a/0900766b8166e575.pdf) connector, its rated as 48V DC 7.5A Max. Another [manual](https://www.kycon.com/Pub_Eng_Draw/KPJX-4S.pdf) from the same manufacturer has the following statement:

[image]

Does it mean the max current is 7.5A at 48V and for example at 12V can this pass more current or still 7.5A?

(I'm stuck with why they state the max current to the voltage by saying **7.5A Max. @ 45V DC**) Does the max current have dependency to voltage in this case?

Answer (score 5):

That rating is intended as "do not exceed either." The current the connector can handle is based on the robustness of the conductors while the voltage it can withstand is based on the insulation and physical separation of the conductors.

Don't mistake it as a "power" rating which might lead you to think you can increase the voltage if you decrease the current.

Comment: However, it should be noted that specifically in the context of switches and relays, there *can* be a power rating having to do with how much power it can break (relating to its ability to withstand sparks). You *might* see it on some connectors, too.

Comment: @Hearth I usually look for both AC and DC voltages and current on switches/relays, since they have make/break requirements that have to take arcing into account. With a zero-crossing in AC they tend to have higher AC voltage tolerances. I am not sure I'd characterize them as having a power rating though (e.g. you can exceed I if you lower E or vice versa).

Comment: I've seen plenty of relays with a switching power rating. See for instance [this datasheet](https://api.pim.na.industrial.panasonic.com/file_stream/main/fileversion/306), page 4. (the first relay I found on digikey)

Comment: @Hearth Ah yes, but those power ratings coexist with max voltage and current ratings as well. In other words, there still exists a ceiling for both voltage and current.

Comment: Right, and there's a power rating on top of that. Not instead.

Comment: @Hearth I think we're in agreement on the same thing just coming at it from opposite sides. :)

Answer (score 1):

No. The current rating is primarily a matter of the heating effect in the connector when passing current. This is simply calculated: power = current squared times resistance.

P = I^2 * R

This heating effect is sometimes called "I squared R losses" for that reason.

The resistance is due to the resistance of the connector conductor itself, and to contact resistance where it touches the other part of the connector. You can see from the formula that this heating effect has nothing to do with voltage. You can have 7.5A at 1V or 7.5A at 48V. The resistance and current are the same.